# Correct way to edit dictionary value python

Tags: python, pep8

I have written the following code in two different ways. I am trying to find the "correct pythonic" way of doing it. I will explain the reasons for both.

First way, EAFP. This one uses pythons EAFP priciple, but causes some code duplication.

```
try:
    my_dict['foo']['bar'] = some_var
except KeyError:
    my_dict['foo'] = {}
    my_dict['foo']['bar'] = some_var
```

Second way, LBYL. LBYL is not exactly considered pythonic, but it removes the code duplication.

```
if 'foo' not in my_dict:
    my_dict['foo'] = {}

my_dict['foo']['bar'] = some_var
```

Which way would be considered best? Or is there a better way?

Comment: I would use the second way. Repeated code isn't nice. Then if `bar` becomes `foo` you need to change it once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say a seasoned Python developer would either use

[dict.setdefault](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) or [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
my_dict.setdefault('foo', {})['bar'] = some_var
```

or

```
from collection import defaultdict
my_dict = defaultdict(dict)
my_dict['foo']['bar'] = some_var
```

Also for the sake of completeness, I will introduce you to a recursive `defaultdict` pattern, which allows for dictionaries with infinite depth without any key error

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> def tree(): return defaultdict(tree)

>>> my_dict = tree()
>>> my_dict['foo']['bar']['spam']['egg'] = 0
>>> my_dict
defaultdict(<function tree at 0x026FFDB0>, {'foo': defaultdict(<function tree at 0x026FFDB0>, {'bar': defaultdict(<function tree at 0x026FFDB0>, {'spam': defaultdict(<function tree at 0x026FFDB0>, {'egg': 0})})})})
```

Comment: I like the options. By providing me both solutions I can choose how it works best in my case. (in this case i cant use defaultdict because the dictionary is given to me)

Answer (score 3):

Use a defaultdict

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                           

from collections import defaultdict                                             

my_dict = defaultdict(dict)                                                     

my_dict['foo']['bar'] = "Hello, defaultdict"                                    

print my_dict['foo']['bar']
```

Answer (score 2):

Better solution:

```
my_dict.setdefault('foo', {})['bar'] = some_var
```

Try looking up the python dictionary get and setdefault methods.

Answer (score 0):

The second way is more pythonic because it does not throw an error where you know one might occur and could easily prevent it.

Comment: It throws an exception that is handled by the except block.

Comment: I disagree, the try-except is usually more appropriate according to pep8